# reusable Bar chart showing bars one over another which have same names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

The problem I am having is my schedules bar Chart have names on the X axis and values on Y axis, names sometimes were so big that I have to do a substring(0,6) to reduce the name size and display full name in the tool tip. By doing that what happened was the schedules which have the same 6 alphabets were overlapped and both were showing one over another. Like below:-
[image: 2 bars showing one over another, both names have *test55* and *test55 (test55)*]

I want to make sure all bars have their own X Axis and they don't overlap each other, even if they have the same 6 alphabets of their names. My application is really complex I won't be able to create a fiddle , but the chart code is below its mostly modified from reusable bar charts 
http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077.

I call this bar chart like this;

```
           var chart   = d3.custom.barChart(),
               chartEl = d3.select(element[0]);
               chartEl.datum(scope.setBarData).call(chart);
```

**Code:-**

```
d3.custom = {};

d3.custom.barChart = function module() {

var dispatch = d3.dispatch('customHover');
function bar(selection) {

    var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
        width = 900,
        height = 420,
        xRoundBands = 0.2,
        xValue = function(d) {
            return d
        },
        yValue = function(d) { return d; },
        xScale = d3.scale.ordinal(),
        yScale = d3.scale.linear(),
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left"),
        data,
        xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale);

    selection.each(function(data) {

        var dataX = data.name.map(function(d, i) {
            return xValue.call(data.name, d, i);
        });

        var  dataY = data.value.map(function(d, i) {
            return yValue.call(data.value, d, i);
        });
        data = d3.zip(dataX, dataY);

        //showing full name of rotation on tool tip on X axis

        var tip = d3.tip()
            .attr('class', 'x-tip')
            .offset([-10,0])
            .html( function (d, i) {
                return "<strong>Rotation Name:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d[0] + "</span></br><strong>Value:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d[1] + "</span>"
            });


        // Update the x-scale.
        xScale
            .domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0].substring(0,6);} ))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], xRoundBands);


        // Update the y-scale.
        yScale
            .domain(d3.extent(data.map(function(d) { return d[1];} )))
            .range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])
            .nice();


        // Select the svg element, if it exists.
        var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

        // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
        var gEnter = svg.enter().append("svg").append("g");
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "bars");
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
        gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis zero");
        svg.call(tip);
        // Update the outer dimensions.
        svg .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        // Update the inner dimensions.
        var g = svg.select("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

        // Update the bars.
        var bar = svg.select(".bars").selectAll(".bar").data(data);
        bar.enter().append("rect");
        bar.exit().remove();
        bar .attr("class", function(d, i) {
            return d[1] < 0 ? "bar negative" : "bar positive";
        })
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return X([d[0].substring(0,6), d[1]]);
            })
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
            .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                return d[1] < 0 ? Y0() : Y(d);
            })
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function(d, i) {
                return Math.abs( Y(d) - Y0() );
            });

        // x axis at the bottom of the chart
        g.select(".x.axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ")")
            .call(xAxis.orient("bottom"));

        // zero line
        g.select(".x.axis.zero")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + Y0() + ")")
            .call(xAxis.tickFormat("").tickSize(0));


        // Update the y-axis.
        g.select(".y.axis")
            .call(yAxis);
        duration = 500;

    });

    // The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
    function X(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
    }

    function Y0() {
        return yScale(0);
    }

    // The x-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
    function Y(d) {
        return yScale(d[1]);
    }

    bar.margin = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return margin;
        margin = _;
        return this;
    };

    bar.width = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return width;
        width = _;
        return this;
    };

    bar.height = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return height;
        height = _;
        return this;
    };

    bar.x = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
        xValue = _;
        return this;
    };
    bar.gap = function(_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return gap;
        gap = _x;
        return this;
    };
    bar.ease = function(_x) {
        if (!arguments.length) return ease;
        ease = _x;
        return this;
    };
    bar.y = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
        yValue = _;
        return this;
    };


}

d3.rebind(bar, dispatch, 'on');
return bar;
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you substring before you send the data to the ordinal scale, so it's creating the same ordinal entries for your shortened names. It's an easy fix:

```
      xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d[0];} ))

      xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {return d.substring(0,6);})
```

You create the scale based on the actual names, you format the axis labels using your shortened strings.

Comment: That solves the overlapping bars , but what about the text on X Axis, it doesn't shows substring, and shows the whole jumbled up strings.

Comment: Thanks for your help it solved the problem when I called above `xAxis.tickformat()` in `g.select(".x.axis");` . Selecting it as answer